# Quadratic bounds of positive semidefinite matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be a positive semidefinite matrix with only one zero eigenvaule, i.e. its eigenvalues are given by the following increasing order $0=\lambda_1<\lambda_2\leq...\leq\lambda_N$. Does this imply the following inequality:

$$\lambda_2x^Tx\leq x^TAx\leq\lambda_Nx^Tx$$

Note that $\lambda_2$ is the second eigenvalue not the minimum one. In graph theory, this is true when $A$ is the Laplacian matrix of a graph. I wonder whether this inequality holds for all semidefinite matrices or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=v_1$ the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1 = 0$.

$$
\lambda_2 x^T x \leq x^T A x \leq \lambda_N x^T x\\
\lambda_2 x^T x \leq 0 \leq \lambda_N x^T x\\
$$

But that's not true. $\lambda_2 x^T x > 0$.

Comment: You are totally right. I have revised the theorem related the Laplacian matrix and the eigenvector associated to the zero eigenvalue is excluded. Thanks a lot.